# how to send message to Tibco Renvdezvous using Java?

Tags: java, tibco, tibco-rv

I'm trying to send message to a Tibco server via Renvdezvous using Java. 
I used the sample code in the installation folder " %TIBRV_HOME%/src/examples/java"

1 - When I run "tibrvclient" example after changing service, daemon, subject.
I found the below message in the console, and the server did not receive any message.

> "Attempting to contact server using subject xxx... 2014-04-30 19:10:15
>   RV: TIB/Rendezvous Error Not Handled by Process: {ADV_CLASS="WARN"
>   ADV_SOURCE="SYSTEM" ADV_NAME="LICENSE.EXPIRE" ADV_DESC="The license
>   will expire" expiretime=2014-04-30 17:20:15Z host="10.0.8.17"}"

2 - When I run "cmsender" example after changing service,daemon, cmname, confirmAdvisorySubject, I found the below messages in the client console

> 2014-04-30 19:15:58 RV: TIB/Rendezvous Error Not Handled by Process:
>   {ADV_CLASS="WARN" ADV_SOURCE="SYSTEM" ADV_NAME="LICENSE.EXPIRE"
>   ADV_DESC="The license will expire" expiretime=2014-04-30 17:25:58Z
>   host="10.0.8.17"}

but the server did not receive any message, and the below error is in the server

> Advisory :
>   ****_RV.ERROR.RVCM.**REGISTRATION.COLLISION****.**ECACTIBCMSAdapt.CMQ
>
> Message  : {, M_TREE {
>       {ADV_CLASS, M_STRING, "ERROR"}
>
> ```
> {ADV_SOURCE, M_STRING, "RVCM"}
>
> {ADV_NAME, M_STRING, "REGISTRATION.COLLISION.ECACTIBCMSAdapt.CMQ"}
>
> {name, M_STRING, "ECACTIBCMSAdapt.CMQ"}
>
> {confl_inbox, M_STRING, "_INBOX.0A000811.2DF453612FCE18B68088.1"}
> {confl_addr, M_UNKNOWN, 10.0.8.17} }}
> ```

any suggestion will be highly appreciated

Comment: What are the sending and receiving settings?  Are the client and the server on the same LAN?

Answer (score 0):

You should put a valid registration file, "tibrv.tkt" in  $TIBRV_HOME/bin and restart the computer.